# setTimeout not working to dissapear <p> tag

Tags: javascript

I'm a fair rookie to JS and I'm working on a project that needs me to make a non-functioning validation system. Here is the code i have at the moment:

I don't know why the setTimeout is not working, I checked on other posts as well but had no understanding. It seems my function dissapearText is not being recognised since i have a console.log as a test to see if it runs, but it's not appearing in the devtools console. Any simple solution would do.

Thanks,
Arthur

```
{
let validation = document.querySelector('.type__style');
let validation2 = document.getElementById("label__text");

const init = () =>{
    const $button = document.getElementById('send__button');
    $button.onclick = () => {
        revealText();
        setTimeout(dissapearText,4000);
    }

    const revealText = () => {
        if (validation.value === ""){
            validation.focus();
            window.alert("Please enter your name.");
            return false;
        }else if(validation2.value === ""){
            validation2.focus();
            window.alert("Please fill in commentary.");
            return false;
        }else{
            document.querySelector('.feedback').style.opacity = 1;
            return true;
        }

    }

    const dissapearText = () => {
        if (revealText === true){
            console.log("sup");
            document.querySelector('.feedback').style.opacity = 0;
        }
    }

}
init();
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The issue is

```
if (revealText === true)
```

`revealText` is a function which **returns** a boolean, you need to change this to

```
if (revealText() === true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I changed the revealText but now I receive the alert message 'please enter your name' after a few seconds, but the p tag's opacity is not changing.

Comment: I figured that it runs the whole function again after pressing the button, if i'm quick enough to fill in the fields before the timer runs out, the opacity does change. the simple solution that worked is just removing the if state, but that's not really a good code, i think?